# Vectorized splatting

Tags: julia

I'd like to be able to splat an array of tuples into a function in a vectorized fashion. For example, if I have the following function,

```
function foo(x, y)
    x + y
end
```

and the following array of tuples,

```
args_array = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
```

then I could use a list comprehension to obtain the desired result:

```
julia> [foo(args...) for args in args_array]
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
  3
  7
 11
```

However, I would like to be able to use the dot vectorization notation for this operation:

```
julia> foo.(args_array...)
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching foo(::Int64, ::Int64, ::Int64)
```

But as you can see, that particular syntax doesn't work. Is there a vectorized way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`foo.(args_array...)` doesn't work because it's doing:

```
foo.((1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6))
# which is roughly equivalent to
[foo(1,3,5), foo(2,4,6)]
```

In other words, it's taking each element of `args_array` as a separate argument and then broadcasting `foo` over those arguments.  You want to broadcast `foo` over the elements directly.  The trouble is that running:

```
foo.(args_array)
# is roughly equivalent to:
[foo((1,2)), foo((3,4)), foo((5,6))]
```

In other words, the broadcast syntax is just passing each tuple as a single argument to `foo`.  We can fix that with a simple intermediate function:

```
julia> bar(args) = foo(args...);

julia> bar.(args_array)
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
  3
  7
 11
```

Now that's doing what you want!  You don't even need to construct the second argument if you don't want to.  This is exactly equivalent:

```
julia> (args->foo(args...)).(args_array)
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
  3
  7
 11
```

And in fact you can generalize this quite easily:

```
julia> splat(f) = args -> f(args...);

julia> (splat(foo)).(args_array)
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
  3
  7
 11
```

Comment: I like the `splat` function. `splat(foo).(args_array)` (without parentheses around `splat(foo)`) works on my machine.

Comment: Yes, the extra parentheses are redundant.

Answer (score 1):

You could `zip` the `args_array`, which effectively transposes the array of tuples:

```
julia> collect(zip(args_array...))
2-element Array{Tuple{Int64,Int64,Int64},1}:
 (1, 3, 5)
 (2, 4, 6)
```

Then you can broadcast `foo` over the transposed array (actually an iterator) of tuples:

```
julia> foo.(zip(args_array...)...)
(3, 7, 11)
```

However, this returns a tuple instead of an array. If you need the return value to be an array, you could use any of the following somewhat cryptic solutions:

```
julia> foo.(collect.(zip(args_array...))...)
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
  3
  7
 11

julia> collect(foo.(zip(args_array...)...))
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
  3
  7
 11

julia> [foo.(zip(args_array...)...)...]
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
  3
  7
 11
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
[foo(x,y) for (x,y) in args_array]
```

Comment: That starts to get verbose if there are a lot of arguments, and it's basically equivalent to `[foo(args...) for args in args_array]`, which I mention in the question.